# Find process from window or vice versa in task manager?

Tags: windows, windows-11, process, window, task-manager

I have multiple instances of an app running. One of the instances is frozen and I want to end it forcefully in Task Manager, while preserving all others.

I'm trying to find it in Task Manager but I can't tell which instance is the troublesome one.

Is there a way to click a process in TM and do 'show window', or any alternative to identify the process or PID from a window?

Comment: If you don't mind installing software, get Process hacker (https://processhacker.sourceforge.io) This task manager replacement (optionally) allows you to see in depth what happens on your system and you can find out what process hangs. It groups processes but you still see the PID and its status. It can even identify which process for services is responsible for what service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Powershell with the following cmdlet to get the processes that are not responding/frozen:

```ps
Get-Process | Where-Object { !$_.Responding }
```

If for example the ID is 345, you can stop it with the cmdlets:

```ps
Get-Process -ID 345 | Stop-Process
```

Comment: That is a cool trick.